# Titanium: Best place for storing secret files

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Since i cant play an audio file from a DB blob, i have to write it as a file, before i can play it.

Looking at the documentation, my choices are:

Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory

Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory

Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory

Ti.Filesystem.applicationCacheDirectory

Considering that i want my file to be secret, so no other app can see that file, what is my best option?

EDIT: So the issue is more with Android, i'm afraid that any file browser will be able to find the file.

Comment: I thing that what you store inside applicationDataDirectory is only accessible by your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're building for android, because ios data are sandboxed and not readily accessible by default (until ios8). Rather than hiding them, just encode them using `base64encode()`. And then you can decode when accessing the file with `base64decode()`.

With that said, I've never had to use it. So, I don't have an example. But you can read about it in the api doc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure i follow. If i base encode it, i get the file as text. The video player requires a file in order to play. So at some point in time i have to save the string as a file. When i do that, i'd like it to not be available to other programs and just by opening the SD card, or via a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if you are building an app for iOS or Android. For example `Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory` is available only for Android (SD card).

Anyway if you want to save an audio file, you should save it in `<Application_Home>/Documents` ,so you should use `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory`. Don't forgot to set up a `remoteBackup` flag see http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-property-remoteBackup

Also have a look at iOS Data Storage Guidelines for more details
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

*If you want to save an audio file only because you need to play it ,but you don't need to store it in a fileSystem then is better to use `Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory`